# Yield return brainfreeze

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a method like this:

```
IEnumerable<record> GetSomeRecords()
{
  while(...)
  {
    yield return aRecord
  }
}
```

Now, lets say I have a caller that also returns an enumerable of the same type, something like this

```
IEnumerable<record> ParentGetSomeRecords()
{
  // I want to do this, but for some reason, my brain locks right here
  foreach(item in someItems)
    yield return GetSomeRecords();
}
```

That code gets syntax error error because yield return wants a type record, and I'm returning an IEnumerable of records

I want one "flat" IEnumerable that flattens a nested loop of enumerables.  It's making me crazy, becuase I know I've done this before, but I can't seem to remember what it was. got any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "one flat IEnumerable" in this case - could you show an example of the expected return type/data?

Comment: Do you **have** to use `yield return`?

Comment: If you just want to return the data as a materialized list (without any data transformation), you could use GetSomeRecords().ToList(). Is that what you want?

Comment: @JMarsch: The relation between `GetSomeRecords()` and `ParentGetSomeRecords()` is not clear; you should describe how they are related. Is `ParentGetSomeRecords()` returning some kind of tree? Is `Record` a self-referencing type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
IEnumerable<record> ParentGetSomeRecords()
{
    foreach(var item in someItems)
        foreach(var record in GetSomeRecords())
            yield return record;
}
```

As noted, this will only work for a single level of children but is the most equivalent of your example code.

**Update**

Some people seem to believe you want the ability to flatten a hierarchical structure. Here is an extension method which performs breadth-first flattening (get the siblings before children):

Coming from a single item:

```
[Pure]
public static IEnumerable<T> BreadthFirstFlatten<T>(this T source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    Contract.Requires(!ReferenceEquals(source, null));
    Contract.Requires(selector != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>() != null);

    var pendingChildren = new List<T> {source};

    while (pendingChildren.Any())
    {
        var localPending = pendingChildren.ToList();
        pendingChildren.Clear();
        foreach (var child in localPending)
        {
            yield return child;
            var results = selector(child);
            if (results != null)
                pendingChildren.AddRange(results);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
record rec = ...;
IEnumerable<record> flattened = rec.BreadthFirstFlatten(r => r.ChildRecords);
```

This will result in an `IEnumerable<record>` containing `rec`, all of recs children, all of the childrens children, etc etc..

If you are coming from a collection of `records`, use the following code:

```
[Pure]
private static IEnumerable<T> BreadthFirstFlatten<T, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TResult> selector, Action<ICollection<T>, TResult> addMethod)
{
    Contract.Requires(source != null);
    Contract.Requires(selector != null);
    Contract.Requires(addMethod != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>() != null);

    var pendingChildren = new List<T>(source);

    while (pendingChildren.Any())
    {
        var localPending = pendingChildren.ToList();
        pendingChildren.Clear();
        foreach (var child in localPending)
        {
            yield return child;
            var results = selector(child);
            if (!ReferenceEquals(results, null))
                addMethod(pendingChildren, results);
        }
    }
}

[Pure]
public static IEnumerable<T> BreadthFirstFlatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    Contract.Requires(source != null);
    Contract.Requires(selector != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>() != null);

    return BreadthFirstFlatten(source, selector, (collection, arg2) => collection.AddRange(arg2));
}

[Pure]
public static IEnumerable<T> BreadthFirstFlatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T> selector)
{
    Contract.Requires(source != null);
    Contract.Requires(selector != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>() != null);

    return BreadthFirstFlatten(source, selector, (collection, arg2) => collection.Add(arg2));
}
```

These two extension methods can be used like so:

```
IEnumerable<records> records = ...;
IEnumerable<record> flattened = records.BreadthFirstFlatten(r => r.ChildRecords);
```

Or from the reverse direction:

```
IEnumerable<record> records = ...;
IEnumerable<record> flattened = records.BreadthFirstFlatten(r => r.ParentRecords);
```

All of these extension methods are iterative so not limited by the stack size.

I have a whole host of these types of methods, including pre-order and post-order depth-first traversal, if you wish to see them, I will make a repo and upload them somewhere :)

Comment: Probably is what he's looking for. +1

Comment: I think his `record` class has a `IEnumerable<record>` so it could be `n` levels deep. This only works for the first level

Comment: @mattytommo I will post an update to my answer in case that is what he is after.

Comment: You can "unroll" recursive sequences using an extension of this approach btw.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Almost what I posted, except my updated code is iterative, no stackoverflows for me ^^

Comment: Your first example is pretty close to what I was looking for - the only difference is that the inner foreach is actually inside of another method that returns an IEnumerable (via yield return).

Comment: @JMarsch You would still need to loop over the results of that other method and yield return them. There's no shorthand way of saying yield return all items of this IEnumerable without a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
IEnumerable<record> ParentGetSomeRecords()
{
    var nestedEnumerable = <whatever the heck gets your nested set>;
    // SelectMany with an identity flattens 
    // IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> to just IEnumerable<T>
    return nestedEnumerable.SelectMany(rec => rec);
}
```

Comment: I think he has a never ending chain of sub-items. This only works on first level sub items.

Comment: @mattytommo Yeah, had to re-read that a couple times...edited with explanatory comment

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient, but you could use this:

```
List<Record> rcrdList = new List<Record>();
foreach (var item in someItems)
{
    rcrdList.AddRange(item.GetSomeRecords());
}
return rcrdList;
```